# RewriteRule with anchor ( %23 ) using NE flag redirects to "302 Found"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I made a one-page website where every menu tab leads to an anchor (#, %23) in the page. However, after visiting the site with its URL (www.example.com), I don't get the first menu tab selected because of my primitive javascript.

So I could

1) edit the javascript (I'm not good at that at all), so I decided for the 2):

2) Write a rewrite rule for redirecting the base URL to the first menu tab link.

### **What I want to achieve**

Redirect

```
www.example.com
```

to

```
www.example.com/#my-anchor
```

### **Possible solution that I tried**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/#my-anchor [R=302,NE,QSA,L]
```

### **What's the problem**

With this rule, I don't get redirected directly. I got to a page with 302 redirect info

```
**Found**

The document has moved here.
```

Where "here" is a link to www.example.com/#my-anchor. That's wrong, I want to be redirected, I don't want to click anywhere. Furthermore, after clicking onto the "here" link, my URL changes to the one requested, but I keep staying on the "302 Found" page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, couldn't figure the htaccess solution out, so I learned jQuery a bit and expanded my JavaScript - it did it's work as well, maybe even in a better way.

I only needed to add these lines into the script which adds 'current' class to a menu tab (ul li) which is more than simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('nav ul li.proc-websimple').addClass('current');
});
```